# Does sizes of img have different behavior in different browsers?

Tags: html, image, responsive-images

I am trying to load different image resolution according to the browser available width. Between 0-767 it is supposed to load the image for 800w above that is supposed to choose what it fit better, in this case, 1000w.

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20"
     srcset="https://dummyimage.com/350x466 350w,
            https://dummyimage.com/400x533 400w, 
            https://dummyimage.com/800x1067 800w, 
            https://dummyimage.com/1000x1334 1000w"
     sizes="(max-width: 767px) 800px"
     alt="Responsive Image Test">
```

I tried this https://codepen.io/TiagoSousa/pen/YJMdWd/ in different browsers (Chrome v.70, Firefox v.63 and v.64.0b6, Safari v.11) in different SO (Windows 10, OSX v.10.14, Android 8.1 and iOS v.11) and it only works as supposed in OSX.
In the other devices, it always loads the image for 1000w.

When I changed the browser resolution I always refreshed the page to force the load.

It is something that I am doing wrong or is something external to my code?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is a result of your sizes attribute. Check out this:

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/350x466 350w, https://dummyimage.com/400x533 400w, https://dummyimage.com/800x1067 800w, https://dummyimage.com/1000x1334 1000w" alt="Responsive Image Test">
```

Picture is automatically changed, when the width of viewport is picture width. But you have limited that on one media query.

Further information:

https://bitsofco.de/the-srcset-and-sizes-attributes/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: But that is what I want, is to force to use a specific size for a specific resolution. For 0-767px I don't want to use the default, I want the browser to use the image for 800, for some browsers it's working but for others it isn't.